# Search Engine: Features

Tags: support, search

There's an article in help center:

- [How do I search?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

And some articles in meta, e.g.:

- [Search automatically assuming tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2872/79762)
- [Improving the search system](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19205/79762)
- [How to search among comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3917/79762)
- [Search Function for Favourites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3477/79762)

Where can I find a comprehensive list of all features?

*(In case there's none, this meta aims to collect all features.)*

Comment: The help center article is comprehensive as far as the built in search engine is concerned. The other articles concern other approaches to searching, involving Data Explorer and external engines.

Comment: @Idisagree: Nope, it doesn't mention to convert names of tags automatically into tags. *(See the first meta article.)*

Comment: The reason it doesn't mention the automatic conversion of names of tags is because that is no longer done. This isn't too surprising, as the first meta article is 4 years old. You can replicate this by performing the search for `algebra [measure-theory]` and noting that the result is not `[algebra] [measure-theory]`.

Comment: @mixedmath Because there is no tag "algebra" anymore. Try `calculus integration`.

Comment: @Idisagree I get interesting behaviour. Typing `calculus [integration]` only gives me questions tagged integration. Typing `calculus integration` gives questions tagged with both. Fascinating